# libexpat could not be found by linux system

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I am developing with vddk library for ubuntu 12.10 i386. I constantly get following error:

```
Cannot open library: libexpat.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

When I run `apt-file search libexpat.so`
it shows me following

```
lib64expat1: /usr/lib64/libexpat.so.1
lib64expat1: /usr/lib64/libexpat.so.1.6.0
lib64expat1-dev: /usr/lib64/libexpat.so
libexpat1: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
libexpat1: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
libexpat1-dev: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so
```

I already tried to create a symlink

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.0
```

but it did not work.
Strange thing:

```
 ls -l `locate libexpat.so`
ls: cannot access /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/vmware-vix-disklib/lib64/libexpat.so.0: No such file or directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 141320 Aug 20 09:21 /home/ubuntu/vddk/lib64/libexpat.so.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   141320 Feb  3 16:45 /usr/lib/vmware-vix-disk-lib/vmware-vix-disk-lib/lib64/libexpat.so.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   141320 Aug 20 09:21 /usr/vmware-vix-disklib-distrib/lib64/libexpat.so.0
```

Comment: How/why are you seeing 64-bit libs on a 32-bit OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by 
manually downloading and installing libexpat package form here 
http://expat.sourceforge.net/ and look for downloading page. It should take you to sourceforge page and select stable package

Comment: For updated link, start with [packages.ubuntu.com/] then find your way down, based on the release.

Answer (score 11):

`apt-file` shows only the contents of a package, or in your case the package(s) by file name, but it works regardless of whether the package is installed or not.

You need to install `libexpat1`:

```
sudo apt-get install libexpat1
```

If you are about to compile and link custom C programs against `libexpat1` you will also need:

```
sudo apt-get install libexpat1-dev
```

Comment: these modules are already installed, but still Im having this error

Comment: On my system it is at `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1`. I would try to `aptitude reinstall libexpat1`

Comment: while building something we require the dev package. Installing the dev package resulted in solving my error. libexpat1 was already there. Thanks @hek

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [source code download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/expat/) and build with the correct flag.

Since you are building for x86, you'll need to run `configure` like this:

```
./configure CFLAGS=-m32
```